# How to make short-living HttpClient (socket problem)

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I have WPF (.net 6.0) application with multiple web-services in its model. Some services have their own HttpClients.
But sometimes I need to make multiple requests within short period of time. The problem is the `HttpClient` must be long-living/reusable, and sockets are garbaged if we create multiple `HttpClient`s for short work. Some of my web-services used only once a day or more rarely.
**Example 1:**
I have 150 proxies. Once a day I need to check all my proxies. Recreating HttpClient 150 times is smell and perfomance could be affected. Keeping these clients as long-living also bad idea.
**Example 2:**
I need to make multiple requests with preset of default headers/proxy/cookies or another combination of unchangable data from HttpClientHandler (unchangable from first request) once a day/week/month.
**Question:**
Is there any a single solution that can solve these problems. Some kind of magical `HttpClient` or `Handler` analog that doesn't have a socket problem and allows you to make a short queue of requests without loss of performance and speed of work.
I've seen something similar to the solution of this problem somewhere, maybe even on MSDN. But I can't find this article anywhere.

Comment: More details on where stuff runs please. aspnet core web or winforms or what? Generally the advice would be to use an injected httpclientfactory and just set headers however you wanna.

Comment: @Nikki9696 WPF (.net 6.0) with multiple web-services based on http requests. I edited question, thanks.

Comment: Here's a little WPF thing about how to add http client factory https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2019/03/13/using-httpclientfactory-with-wpf-on-net-core-3-0/

Comment: @Nikki9696 Looks like a solution I've seen before and couldn't find. I need to read more about this. Thank you.